# Isolated storage operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream all of a sudden

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I completed this part of my project some weeks ago and it worked perfectly. Having moved to another part I didn't even touch the previous code at all. All of a sudden I can't even open a txt file using isolatedstorage. All I get is this 'operation not permitted' exception.

```
string fileSource = "Favorites.txt";

        using (IsolatedStorageFile myFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileSource, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, myFile)))
            {
                while (reader.Peek() != -1)
                    myList.Add(reader.ReadLine());
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
```

I get the same exception with every part of my code that uses isolatedstorage. The above one is just a small part of it. I close my writers/readers on everyting also.

Comment: Something still has the file opened. Either try restarting your emulator, or check carefully for concurrent operations on the file.

Comment: If you try for example to delete or rename the file, what happens?